# How can i send an image using markdown syntax in an embed discord.py

Tags: python, image, markdown, discord.py, embed

I have this code to display my project's status :

```py
def status(branch):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Wng status", description=f"**On branch : {branch} :**\n\n- Windows : ![WinStatus](https://img.shields.io/github/workflow/status/Wmanage/wng/Rust/{branch})\n- *nix : ![WinStatus](https://img.shields.io/github/workflow/status/Wmanage/wng/RustUnix/{branch})", color=0xffaa00)
    embed.set_footer(text="w/status • Status of wng project")
    return embed
```

But it doesn't display images when i send it :
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHnE.png)

How could i send markdown images ?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 possible locations to add an image to your embed.

[image]

You might consider adding the photos as emojis in your guild and the use them as follows

```py
branch_emoji=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="NAME_HERE")
```

Comment: The problem is that it is dynamic photos, that work with ghub actions :/

Comment: Then you might just many embeds, each one with a branch.